# How to generate grouped by minutes in given day, max min and avg for time range in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, time, database-performance, postgres-9.6

Hello I have been trying to generate a report based on some db data.
I need to calculate per DAY (finished) so in this case lets say that the day for calculation will be : (2001-01-02) and in current date we are in the 2001-01-03. 
So basically day before current date.

- MAX count for locker_orders occupancy in that day + time of occurrence (peak max load of lockers per place)
- Min count for locker_orders occupancy in that day + time of occurrence
  (peak min load of lockers per place)
- AVG count for locker_orders occupancy in that day (average load in that day based on min max and the number of lockers per place)
- group PER place_id
- group PER each minute in current day
- NUMBER of all lockers in store on that day (may change in time)
- Where there is no pickup date the locker is still occupied - it may move to another days span

I was able to perform a simple query to group by place and per minute the locker order was created at but currently i have a problem placing it in current day scope

here is a representation of the timeline (handmade ;))

[image: timeline]

Given a schema of data containing

DB DATA

- LOCKERS

```
------------------------------------
| id |        created_at           |
------------------------------------
|  1 | 2001-01-01 00:00 (DATETIME) |
------------------------------------
|  2 | 2001-01-01 00:00 (DATETIME) |
------------------------------------
|  3 | 2001-01-01 00:00 (DATETIME) |
------------------------------------
|  4 | 2001-01-01 00:00 (DATETIME) |
------------------------------------
|  5 | 2001-01-01 00:00 (DATETIME) |
------------------------------------
```

- LOCKER_ORDERS

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |          created_at         |        pickup_date     | place_id |  locker_id |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 2001-01-02 10:00 (DATETIME) |  2001-01-02 13:25 (DATETIME) |  1  |     2     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 | 2001-01-02 07:45 (DATETIME) |  2001-01-02 11:50 (DATETIME) |  1  |     1     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 | 2001-01-02 19:30 (DATETIME) |            NULL              |  1  |     4     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  4 | 2001-01-01 14:40 (DATETIME) |  2001-01-01 21:15 (DATETIME) |  1  |     5     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5 | 2001-01-02 12:25 (DATETIME) |            NULL              |  1  |     3     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6 | 2001-01-02 13:30 (DATETIME) |  2001-01-02 18:40 (DATETIME) |  1  |     2     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  7 | 2001-01-02 12:45 (DATETIME) |  2001-01-02 20:50 (DATETIME) |  1  |     1     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  8 | 2001-01-02 07:40 (DATETIME) |  2001-01-02 18:15 (DATETIME) |  1  |     5     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

OUTPUT DATA - the desired output

```
# | Date (day) | place_id | min | max | avg | NO of all lockers in that day in given place |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | 2001-01-02 |   1      |  0  |  4  |  2  |      8      |
```

Comment: Is a day just 24hrs from the `created_at` time or specific to a date? I'm a little confused by the `locker_orders` having more than one date with respect to your question. Can you clarify finished/past day for me? Also, one of your bullets says "group per minute" but your desired output has no time involved.

Comment: The min and max columns are the reason for per minute calculations? So you can say at any given minute this was the min/max?

Comment: Yes exactly that is the reason for minutes :)

Comment: Also any locker order may be in a locker from a day before till next day or even further.  So I am not sure about the created at column in context of time.  It is almost like the given day is not in a column but as a separate entity outside being the time scope for calculation.

Comment: You're going to need a function for this with some sort of bounds (start_time, end_time). I've been doing some thinking on this. Not an easy problem to solve but I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: Any help would be wonderful :) Thank You